# Place AdmobBanner at the bottom inside a Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, admob

I have to insert an AdMob Banner in the app that I am creating. For the layout I use a SingleChildScrollView with a Column inside. Within the latter there are the various widgets each consisting of a container.
I would like to place an AdmobBanner created with the admob_flutter plugin at the bottom of the page but I have not succeeded.
I thank all those who will help me

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(APPNAME),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () { Share.share(); },
                child: Icon(Icons.share, size: 26.0,),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ...,
                Container( alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: AdmobBanner(adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", 
                          adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER),
                ),
          ],
        )),
        drawer: new Elements().drawer(context),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Stack` Widget

It will keep your `adBanner` stick to bottom and even bring it to top of keyboard
if keyboard is open

replace your code shown in `body` with below shown code

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            //padding used for adding space to the bottom of widget list
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
            child: _buildScrollableLayout()),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child:  AdmobBanner(adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", 
                      adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER),
        ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: As you can see in the link if I change the height of the text the banner moves. I want this to always be down [https://ibb.co/album/h8QnmF](https://ibb.co/album/h8QnmF)

Comment: yeah but the code isn't restricting adbanner size, did you try the code

Comment: In the end I solved with the "Align" Widget set with `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter`